# Outer addition and subtraction in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is the an equivalent operation (or series of operations) that acts like the numpy outer functions?

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(3)
b = np.arange(5)

print np.subtract.outer(a,b)

[[ 0 -1 -2 -3 -4]
 [ 1  0 -1 -2 -3]
 [ 2  1  0 -1 -2]]
```

The obvious candidate [`tf.sub`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#sub) seems to only act elementwise.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
sess.run(tf.transpose([tf.range(3)]) - tf.range(5))
```

Output

```
array([[ 0, -1, -2, -3, -4],
       [ 1,  0, -1, -2, -3],
       [ 2,  1,  0, -1, -2]], dtype=int32)
```

To be more specific, given `(3, 1)` and `(1, 5)` arrays, broadcasting is mathematically equivalent to tiling the arrays into matching `(3, 5)` shapes and doing operation pointwise

[image]

This tiling is internally implemented by looping over existing data, so no extra memory is needed. When given unequal ranks with shapes like `(3, 1)` and `(5)`, broadcasting will pad smaller shape with`1's` *on the left*. This means that 1D list like `tf.range(5)` is treated as a row-vector, and equivalent to `[tf.range(5)]`

Comment: Thanks Yaroslav, this is perfect! Is this exactly equivalent to using `tf.tile` or is this way using broadcasting more efficient?

Comment: It's more efficient, it doesn't actually duplicate the data in memory like tile

Comment: What is a possible mathematical notation for this operation? I mean the tiling of the column vector [0,1,2] into the 3x4 matrix [0,0,0,0; 1,1,1,1; 2,2,2,2]?